# To network a LAN Connected Desktop and Wifi Connected laptop on same router

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router

If I ping my desktop (Connected via LAN cable) from laptop (Connected via Wifi) with Static IPv4 it says Destination host unreachable both computer are windows 7 and connected to the same router (D-Link 2750 U).

How can I network this two machine one connected via UTP cable (LAN) and other with Wifi.

[This image will help you to understand the network I want to make.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Senig.jpg)

Comment: Does the firewall of the clients allow ICMP packets to pass through?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your router is isolating the clients. Routers have this security setting where they may/may not allow the clients to communicate with each other. This is usually set for public WiFis but not for home WiFis.

This is called as wireless isolation. I would recommend that you access your router settings and disable it. You'll need to search around but it'll be either called "wireless isolation" or "AP isolation" or something similar. Here are two images that show this.

[image]

[image]

Once you've disabled this, restart the router, get both clients to try again.

If this also fails then try disabling the firewalls on both machines. If that works then you can narrow down the cause at least.